# ggplot - linechart with panel data doesn't work / plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have following dataset:

- 60k observations of individual bank branches with most relevant balance sheet figures

Currently want to do the following:

- plot net interest rate margin (a % figure, interest rate income/total interest bearing asset) for each country in my dataset

What I did to prepare the data was:

```
by_country <- filtered %>% 
  group_by(countryname,fiscalyear)%>% 
  summarize(net_margin=mean(net_margin))
```

Note that I've already calculated the net_margin colum before.

```
My dataset (dataframe) now looks like this: 

countryname fiscalyear net_margin    ID
   <fct>       <fct>           <dbl> <int>
 1 Australia   2010             3.09     1
 2 Australia   2011             2.69     2
 3 Australia   2012             3.10     3
 4 Australia   2013             3.04     4
 5 Australia   2014             2.96     5
 6 Australia   2015             3.33     6
 7 Australia   2016             3.40     7
 8 Australia   2017             3.47     8
 9 Austria     2010             4.42     9
10 Austria     2011             3.94    10
```

I've also added the ID in the last colum manually.

What I don't get is how to create a simple line chart with ggplot now. I saw other threads in which users wrote that one has to specificy the ID within the group = ... command. I did that as well and it did not work.

Simple ggplot code would look like this:

```
ggplot(by_country, aes(x=fiscalyear, y=net_margin, col=countryname))+
geom_line()
```

The graph then looks like this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To confirm, `ggplot(by_country, aes(x=fiscalyear, y=net_margin, col=countryname, group=countryname))+geom_line()` gave the same result? If so, please add the output of `dput(head(by_country,20))` to your question so we can reproduce the chart + error.

Comment: thank you very much! with group=countryname it works. Before I used the ID in the group = ... ; do I always need to use that group command with panel data structure when plotting linegraphs? I did not really understand that from the other questions I found

Comment: By default, ggplot2 uses all the discrete variables for grouping. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html   In your case, you have fiscalyear as a factor, which is atypical. ggplot is using year + country to group, which means each group has only one value. You can either specify the grouping is only by country, or change fiscalyear to a continuous numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `aes(col=countryname)` in the `geom_line()`.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(by_country, aes(x=fiscalyear, y=net_margin ))+
  geom_line(aes(col=countryname), size=2)+
  labs(x="Fiscal year", y="Net margin", color="Country name")+
  theme_economist()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text( color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
 by_country<-structure(list(countryname = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Austria"), fiscalyear = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2010, 2011), net_margin = c(3.09, 2.69, 
3.1, 3.04, 2.96, 3.33, 3.4, 3.47, 4.42, 3.94), ID = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```